# Pytorch RuntimeError: mat1 & mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied(1x2 and 10000x100)

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, pytorch, nltk

I am trying to build a spam classifier. However, when sending a POST request, I am getting this error.

`RuntimeError at /classify/ mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x2 and 10000x100)`

Yes, it's quite straightforward, but even when adjusting the variables, I still get the same result.
How can I solve this issue?

My model.py file:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import re
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('punkt')

try:
    wordnet.ensure_loaded()
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('wordnet')

class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(10000, 100)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(10, 2)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.flatten(x)
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = self.linear3(x)
        return x

def classify_spam(message):
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load('W:/SpamOrHamProject/SpamOrHamBack/api/AIModel/SpamClassification.pth'))
    model.eval()
    
    cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=10000)
    processed_message = preprocess_message(message)
    vectorized_message = cv.fit_transform([processed_message]).toarray()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        tensor_message = Variable(torch.from_numpy(vectorized_message)).float()
        output = model(tensor_message)
        _, predicted_label = torch.max(output, 0)
    
    return 'Spam' if predicted_label.item() == 1 else 'Not Spam'

def preprocess_message(message):
    remove_non_alphabets = lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', x)
    tokenize = lambda x: word_tokenize(x)
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stem = lambda w: [ps.stem(x) for x in w]
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    leammtizer = lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in x]

    processed_message = remove_non_alphabets(message)
    processed_message = tokenize(processed_message)
    processed_message = stem(processed_message)
    processed_message = leammtizer(processed_message)
    processed_message = ' '.join(processed_message)

    return processed_message
```

And there my model for spam classification

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import os
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import PorterStemmer
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

nltk.download("wordnet")
nltk.download("punkt")

os.makedirs("W:/SpamOrHamProject/SpamOrHamModel/nltk_data", exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs("W:/SpamOrHamProject/SpamOrHamModel/input", exist_ok=True)

data = pd.read_csv(r"W:/SpamOrHamProject/SpamOrHamModel/input/spam_or_not_spam.csv")
data.dropna(inplace=True)
data['label'] = data['label'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else 0)

remove_non_alphabets = lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', x)
tokenize = lambda x: word_tokenize(x)
ps = PorterStemmer()
stem = lambda w: [ps.stem(x) for x in w]
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
leammtizer = lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in x]

data['email'] = data['email'].apply(remove_non_alphabets)
data['email'] = data['email'].apply(tokenize)
data['email'] = data['email'].apply(stem)
data['email'] = data['email'].apply(leammtizer)
data['email'] = data['email'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

max_words = 10000
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=max_words, stop_words='english')
sparse_matrix = cv.fit_transform(data['email']).toarray()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sparse_matrix, np.array(data['label']))

class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(10000, 100)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(10, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = self.linear3(x)
        return x

model = LogisticRegression()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
x_train = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train)).float()
y_train = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train)).long()

epochs = 180
model.train()
loss_values = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y_pred = model(x_train)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)
    loss_values.append(loss.item())
    pred = torch.max(y_pred, 1)[1].eq(y_train).sum()
    acc = pred * 100.0 / len(x_train)
    print('Epoch: {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}%'.format(epoch+1, loss.item(), acc.numpy()))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

plt.plot(loss_values)
plt.title('Loss Value vs Epochs')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend(['Loss'])
plt.show()

x_test = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_test)).float()
y_test = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_test)).long()
model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = model(x_test)
    _, predicted_labels = torch.max(y_pred, 1)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_labels)

class_labels = ['Non-Spam', 'Spam']

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', xticklabels=class_labels, yticklabels=class_labels)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Labels')
plt.ylabel('True Labels')
plt.show()

with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = model(x_test)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_test)
    pred = torch.max(y_pred, 1)[1].eq(y_test).sum()
    print("Accuracy: {}%".format(100 * pred / len(x_test)))

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'W:/SpamOrHamProject/SpamOrHamBack/api/AIModel/SpamClassification.pth')
```

I'm trying to send a POST request with a message, and I expect it to be classified as spam or not spam.

Comment: there are 2 blocks of code in the question.   which one contains the error ?

Comment: in model.py. There an error